# How to toggle classes of iframe in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the iframe (a **chatbot html** page) , which I am calling in another HTML project. So, i need to toggle the classes (shown below) **as an *onclick* event or by any other functions**

**chatbot html page=>** there is a logo, which I placed in bottom right and when someone clicking on that logo, a **form** div is opening... this project I'm calling in another project inside iframe

```
    <iframe id="overlayDiv" class="overlayDiv" src="http://127.0.0.1:5501/index.html" frameborder="0"</iframe>
```

**classes for toggling**

```
<style>
            .overlayDiv {
                border: 1px solid red;
                z-index: 999;
                position: fixed;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                height: 91px;
                width: 92px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
    
            .overlayDivActive {
                height: 470px;
                width: 390px;
                position: fixed;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                z-index: 999;
                border: 1px solid red;
            }
        </style>
```

*for that , below functionality is not working*

```
$(document).ready(() => {
        
            $('#overlayDiv').click(function (e) {
                $('#overlayDiv').toggleClass('overlayDivActive')
            })

        })
```

Comment: What have you tried, what part in particular are you having problems with?

Comment: @CBroe the above mentioned functionality is not working !!!

Comment: I would guess that you probably don't get a click event on the iframe element, because the content _within_ the iframe already "consumes" that click event.

Comment: @CBroe so, what is the solution. when I am clicking in that logo, a form div is coming... but thats inside the iframe (so i can only see some areas of form)...actually i need to change the iframe size according to that form

Comment: You should start by presenting a _proper_ [mre] of your issue, instead of talking about stuff we have not even seen yet. Stuff like _"a form div is coming"_ is absolutely vague.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unsure what you're trying to achieve exactly. You can make use of

```js
//js
document.getElementById("overlayDiv").classlist.toggle("someClass");
//jQuery
$(".overlayDiv").toggle();
```

if that is what you're referring to.

You may or may not find this to be useful as well: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp
I hope this helps a little bit since you've given minimal examples

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of these two options and it will work for you. The important thing is that you order well what you have to do.

This would be using Javascript

```js
document.getElementById("overlayDiv").classlist.toggle('active');
```

This would be using jquery

```js
$(".overlayDiv").toggle('active');
```

This will add the 'active' class to your tag, so now you can work on your css like this

```css
.overlayDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 999;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 91px;
  width: 92px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlayDiv.active {
  height: 470px;
  width: 390px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The toggle is a very powerful tool that you will use more than once in projects.

I hope this helps you.